# Transfer Directory structure from Windows to AIX server

Tags: unix, ssh, ftp

I have to transfer a folder structure from Windows to AIX server but I can not install anything more then Putty as this is client machine.

I have tried few alternative.

1. Tried to ftp Directory structure which is not possible as FTP support only simple file transfer
2. Tried to execute remote UNIX command execution with `putty.exe -ssh -l username -pw password cmd_file.sh`. `cmd_file.sh` is in local windows system contains shell commands but unzip not supported here. I also tried `putty.exe -ssh -l username -pw password unix_command` and got error "invalid port number"
3. I tried to execute a shell script file in unix server from windows, it didn't work either.

Comment: How about zipping up and sending the zip through?

Answer (score 0):

Make a tar file (using cygwin perhaps on Windows -- you do use cygwin, right?). Then ftp the tarball over. Untar, profit!